# Search for a certain name followed by any number (or no number)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to search for a field matching a name followed by a number of variable size (including no number), but I can't see how to use the wildcards on PATINDEX and LIKE to detect an unknown number of digits.

This is the regexp I would like to check : MYNAME[1-9]*

It has to recognize MYNAME, MYNAME5, MYNAME12, MYNAME275, ...

It shouldn't recognize ANOTHERNAME, MYNAMEXX12, MYNAME12X5, MYNAME12X

PATINDEX and LIKE don't recognize the * on the regexp to indicate a variable number of digits.

Do you know of a way to search for a pattern where a part has a variable size ?.

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server uses `%` not `*` as a string wildcard; [LIKE (Transact-SQL) - Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments). SQL Server doesn't support REGEX, it has it's own pattern matching syntax.

Comment: It's a Regular Expression, I'm not using * as a wildcard but as an indicator of zero or more iterations of the previous set. I would like to translate that Regular Expression to a Pattern recognized by PATINDEX or LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    Field   VARCHAR(32)
)



 INSERT @Test( Field )
    VALUES
    ('MYNAME'),
    ('MYNAME5'),
    ('MYNAME12'),
    ('MYNAME275'),
    ('MYNAME275TEXT')


SELECT *
FROM @Test
WHERE (
    (   Field = 'MYNAME' 
        OR Field LIKE 'MYNAME[0-9]%'
    )
    AND Field NOT LIKE 'MYNAME[0-9]%[^0-9]%'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, it´s very close to what I'm looking for, but it recognizes MYNAMEXX12 and it should'nt.

Comment: I've corrected my answer - I thought `MYNAME` was just a sample.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering. MYANAME is just a sample, I want the records matching a certain name followed by any number (or no number). Your corrected answer still matches MYNAMEXX12, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a wild card (geddit?) guess, however, perhaps this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('MYNAME'),('MYNAME5'),('MYNAME12'),('MYNAME275'),('MYNAME654A'))V(N)
WHERE V.N = 'MYNAME'
   OR (V.N LIKE 'MYNAME[0-9]%'
  AND  V.N NOT LIKE 'MYNAME[0-9]%[^0-9]');
```

Comment: Close, thank you, but it also recognizes MYNAME5A1 and I would like the second part to be completely numeric.